# How can I stop temporary webextension without shutdown browser?

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I was executing webextension on Firefox for testing with `about:debugging` menu.
Then tests are done, I want to stop it.

I am looking for a way to stop without shutdown browser, but I can't find a way to stop it out.

Is there way for do it without shutdown browser?

Answer (score 1):

Just like a normal add-on, you can disable or remove a temporary WebExtension that was loaded from `about:debuging` from `about:addons` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>, or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> on OSX) .  If you "Remove" it, and then refresh `about:debugging` you will see that it is gone from that list.

If you do not refresh `about:debugging` after disabling or removing it, it will remain in the list that is displayed. This can be convenient if you are testing behavior when the add-on is installed or removed.

The following gif shows loading and removing an add-on named "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa - demo add-on":

[image: Load and remove temporary add-on]

If you do not refresh `about:addons` after removing an add-on, the add-on will remain in the "uninstalling" state. From that state you can "Undo" the removal/uninstall.  This is displayed in `about:addons` with the "Undo" link.  The fact that an extension is in this state is not available to WebExtension add-ons, but can be seen from other Firefox add-ons using the [Add-on Manager API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager). The Add-on Manager API is *not* compatible with WebExtensions. If you want to take a look at a Firefox Add-on SDK based add-on that shows these states, you can see [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39230741/3773011).